# Solve Diophantine equation: $15^x + 5^y = 3^z + 7^t$ in positive integers.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

This is one of the problems that my teacher gave out, in which he mentioned that $(x, y, z, t) = (2, 2, 5, 1)$ is the only solution to this equation. However, I haven't been able to prove this at all or find any solutions for this problem, so far I have only found out that $x, y$ are both even and $z$ is divisible by $5$.

Comment: Please work out how you found this out , this may give other users an idea how to proceed.

Comment: Seems that positive integers are reuqired since otherwise $x=y=z=t=0$ would also be a solution.

Comment: Using mod 3 $y$ is even, using mod 5 $z, t$ have the same parity, using mod 8 $x$ is even, using mod 25 $z$ is divisible by 5.

Comment: Right, it works this way, compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350987/solve-space-3x-5y-7z-11w?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation is solved [here](https://msp.org/pjm/1982/101-2/pjm-v101-n2-p02-s.pdf), in Theorem $4.22$ on page $279$, by Brenner and Foster. The only nonnegative integral solutions are
$$
(0,0,0,0), \;(1,0,2,1),\; (2,2,5, 1).
$$
One of the intermediate results is Lemma $4.224$, where it is shown that
$$  
(x,y,z,t)\equiv  (2,2,5,1) \bmod 60.
$$